# Can't get correct value from Redis through Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

I'm stuck on this for quite some time. For token management, I'm using Redis. On the Redis, each token keeps a list of all the invoices my customers can see.

For my example, my customer X can view the invoice Y. But the information Y doesn't make it once it goes through Java.

For instance, on redis, the command

```
hget TokenDocumentsEntity:[UUID key] metadata.documents.source.elementData[0]
```

give me back Y. This is what I want and need. Overall, every information I can see using

```
hgetall
```

are correct. This means my code properly writes what I want.
But when I try to get the info from the redis (using @Repository and findById)
It gives me back :

```
tokenDocuments(owner=Id_of_the_customer, documents={name_of_source=[49]})
```

I have no clue where is this 49 coming from, what it is related to or what it represents. But that's the place where my Y should be.

Any clue why this happen?

EDIT : here is the code where this happens:
on the controller :

```
    @PostMapping("/base64")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getDocument(@Valid @RequestBody FileRequest fileRequest, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders header) {

        TokenClaims tokenClaims = validateHeaderAndGetTokenClaims(header);
        TokenDocuments tokenDocuments = newTokenService.getTokenDocuments(tokenClaims.getTokenDocumentsId());

        Audit auditDao = iAuditService.getBackBone(Bill, "listBills", Customer, String.valueOf(tokenClaims.getSubject()));
.
.
.
```

And on the NewTokenService Implementation :

```
    @Override
    public TokenDocuments getTokenDocuments(UUID uuid) {
        Optional<TokenDocumentsEntity> optional = tokenDocumentsRepository.findById(uuid);

        if (optional.isPresent()) {
            logger.debug("optional : " + optional);
            return optional.get().getMetadata();
        }

        throw new EntityNotFoundException("entity with uuid " + uuid + " not found on token db");
    }
```

the debugging tool shows me that

```
uuid = 18906e40-9156-457e-9069-9e849ec663e2
```

which is a key found on my redis, thus fine.
but also

```
optional = Optional[TokenDocumentsEntity(id=18906e40-9156-457e-9069-9e849ec663e2, metadata=TokenDocuments(owner=1041403, documents={SWS=[49]}))]
```

All I send is a FileRequest fileRequest of the form :

```
{
    "fileId": 101520529,
    "fileExtension": "PDF",
    "fileName": "2019-FLN-1000003001",
    "fileSource": "SWS"
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please show us the code where you insert data and where you retrieve it. Also if you have any configuration. You need to provide us with enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: why don't you extract what you want from the response instead of trying to get the exact response? I suppose what you want is simply the owner field? Also, is the 49 similar for different objects? or is it unique to each object when queried? Depending on your answer, it could be some metadata related to the object.

Comment: Sorry @Shawrup, I know it lacks any code. I thought a general description could ring any bell. I will add my code in a couple of minutes.

Comment: The owner field is correct (in this particular case, it is 1041403). What I want is not 49 but something like "101520529". I will add a new entry to see if that changes anything. Thank you for the support @berlin

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

In my

```
tokenDocuments
```

the variable `documents` was a `HashMap` which are not supported by Redis.
I fixed this by using converters instead.

Thank you to anyone who tried to help.